# Prevent waiting for command line output

Tags: php, command-line, command

I thought that this would run without waiting for an output:

```
php /scripts/htdocs/summaries.live/app/scripts/generate-pdfs.php live 1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But it's not happening.  PHP's exec() function is waiting for an output.  How can I work around this to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Without knowing what your script does, we can hardly answer your question.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig I don't agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing  `&` on the end of command

```
php /scripts/htdocs/summaries.live/app/scripts/generate-pdfs.php live 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: That command runs a PHP script `/scripts/htdocs/summaries.live/app/scripts/generate-pdfs.php` with arguments "live 1" and hides the output and standard error stream.

Answer (score 0):

If running something with `exec`, [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) states

> **Note:**
>
> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.